# how to use multi models into TENANT_MODEL

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

im trying to implement tenancy app using [django-tenants](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) but when i try to makemigrations it raise this error , i have to use multi models into TENANT_MODEL but it raise this error

> AssertionError: ForeignKey(('users.User','rooms.Room','rooms.City')) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'

my django version is **3.2**

```
from django_tenants.models import TenantMixin, DomainMixin

class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin,TenantMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #others
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    objects = AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
         return True

class Domain(DomainMixin):
     pass

class Room(TenantMixin):
    room_no = models.IntegerField()
    beds = models.IntegerField(default=2)
```

here is my settings.py

```
SHARED_APPS = [
   'django_tenants',
   'users',
   'rooms',
   'rosetta',
   'widget_tweaks',
   'import_export',

   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]

TENANT_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]

TENANT_MODEL = (
    "users.User","rooms.Room","rooms.City"
)
#but it wont allow me to write all of the apps , it only expect one model !

TENANT_DOMAIN_MODEL = "users.Domain"
```

middleware classes at the top

```
'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware',
```

my database setting

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
```

others settings

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
    'django_tenants.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_tenants.storage.TenantFileSystemStorage'
```

thank you for helping ..

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: https://dpaste.com/6QAEBMBMU stackoverflow wont allow alot of code i used dpaste

Comment: @KlausD. i posted into dpaste

Comment: Here on Stack Overflowall relevant information have to be posted in the question itself.

Comment: @KlausD. its simple you can open the link

Comment: Links can and will die. So, the rule on Stack Overflow is: no links!